# Custon api request in ng-admin

Tags: ng-admin

I need to customize GET and PUT request for the field in Edition view.

For example I have two entities in my app: 'Companies' `api/v1/companies` and 'Journals' `api/v1/journals`.

In Edition view for 'Journals' `api/v1/journals/1/edit` one of the field should be a composite, based on crossing of entities `api/v1/journals/1/companies?companyType=client`. Gets companies of the specified type related to the specified journal

This request responce is array of objects

```
[{"id":3,"name":"Hardworking Monkeys","type":"client"},
 {"id":5,"name":"Other Monkeys","type":"client"}]
```

This field is a "reference_many" field.

[field view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeVtx.png)

And PUT request for this field `api/v1/journals/{journalId}/companies?companyType=` should PUT array with IDs of the companies

So, the question is:
Is it possible to realize such logic?